# How do I get startActivity() to play the finish() animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an activity that I'm currently overriding the back button on in my app (as to update the list in the prior activity with the information inserted at the current activity). To achieve the desired effect I'm using an AsyncTask which starts an activity. Functionally it works as desired, but the animations are unfortunately off (considering that the "slide" that plays when changing activities is in the wrong direction, as if a new acitivty was started instead of the desired animation that plays when finish() is called).

How would I go about solving this problem?

EDIT: The solution to the problem:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you need

```
//Calls a new Activity  
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));  

//Set the transition -> method available from Android 2.0 and beyond  
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in,R.anim.push_up_out);
```

The rest of the code here: [Changing the animation between Activities](http://www.41post.com/3368/programming/android-changing-the-animation-between-activities)

Comment: Thank you. I would like to make use of the standard android animations, which resources would I reference for this? Also, does this override only the current transition? The last time I made use of that function, my test device "freaked out", and all animations broke until reboot.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution - refer to main post for code

Comment: Be careful as the "default android animations" can change. For example, in Android 4,  activities no longer slide left and right when started/finished. They pop in and out. (probably because of tablet screen sizes which would look silly sliding such a large area)